# How can I log into SalesForce using JMeter?

Tags: soap, jmeter, salesforce, token, sessionid

I need to login into Salesforce using JMeter in order to create Cases, Leads, etc.

I saw that is possible login into Salesforce using JMeter. I saw that you need to use a token, session id and more. I feel like it's not explained well enough.

I don't have the process clear at all.

Can u guys help me?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

1. Record the login process using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) or [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-The-BlazeMeter-Chrome-Extension-Record-JMeter-Selenium-or-Synchronized-JMeter-and-Selenium) - you will get a project "skeleton"
2. Record it one more time
3. Compare generated Test Plans - you will see some differences in request parameters, it means that the parameters are **dynamic** and they're a subject to [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start). It means that you will need to inspect previous response, look for the dynamic parameter value, extract it using a suitable JMeter [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) and store it into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)
4. Replace recorded hard-coded values with the variables from step 3
5. Add [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your Test Plan
6. Your login should be successful now

Comment: Thanks!! I was able to record the login access (step 1 and 2), but now I have doubs about step 3. I have the "skeleton" [Imgur](https://i.imgur.com/yCwmeTp.png) but I don't know the dates I need to extract. And in Post-processor, what steps I need to do? below 18.8 Post-Processors?

Comment: Install [Taurus](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/taurus-new-star-test-automation-tools-constellation) tool and run `bzt your-test.yaml -gui` - it will bring up ]JMeter GUI](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#Open-JMeter-GUI) with the generated test plan.

Comment: I got this message: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 96 when Taurus is generating the test plan.